# What is the difference between a probability distribution on events and random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

For the purpose of simplicity, assume everything below is only in the discrete domain.

A $\text{probability space}$ is usually defined as a triple $(\Omega , 2^\Omega , P)$ where

$\Omega := \text{set of outcomes}$

$2^\Omega:= \text{set of events (for simplicity)}$

$P:= \text{mapping from } 2^\Omega \mapsto [0,1] \text{ which assigns a probability to each event}$

My first question is whether $P$ is a *probability distribution* or a *probability measure*, and what exactly is the difference between these two ideas.

Moreover, I am trying to understand where the concept of a $\text{random variable}$ fits in with all this.

From my reading a random variable (over the probability space above) $X:= \text{mapping from } \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.

When we say $P(X=a)$, is this $P$ referring to the same probability distribution of the space? What exactly is the object $X=a$? I would think it refers to the set of all outcomes in $\Omega$ that map to $a$ but my reading does not elucidate this.

What is the ultimate confusion is the statement: $\text{we will use the notation} P(X) \text{ to denote the distribution of the random variable X}$

Again, what exactly is meant by the probability distribution $P$ here? Does it also refer to the $P$ of the probability space that $X$ is defined over? How is this distribution different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Probability distribution* and *probability measure* are synonyms.

$[X=a]=X^{-1}(\{a\})=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=a\}$ hence $P(X=a)=P(X^{-1}(\{a\}))$.

The distribution of the random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is the unique probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ defined by $\mu(B)=P(X\in B)$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, where $[X\in B]=X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in B\}$.

Comment: great response, but what does B(R) mean?

Comment: Borel sigma-algebra on R.

Comment: @carmichael561 When you accept an edit, please check that it does not change the *mathematical* meaning of the post. In the present case, "$X(\omega)\in \mathcal{B}$" is absurd, "$X(\omega)\in B$" is correct.

Comment: @Shailesh When you accept an edit, please check that it does not change the *mathematical* meaning of the post. In the present case, "$X(\omega)\in \mathcal{B}$" is absurd, "$X(\omega)\in B$" is correct.

Comment: This is a terrible answer in my opinion, no matter OP accepting it. The question is clear, concise and directed towards beginners of the topic. You, on the other hand, answer in an obscure and expert manner. Someone starting to study probability does not know what a borel sigma-algebra is, and surely will just get confused on your answer. If you introduce a new concept, you should define it, and show how this fits into your answer.

Comment: For instance, how does a beginner know that $X$ admits an inverse $X^{-1}$? Does even $X^{-1}$ refers to the inverse? What is the meaning of the notation $[X=a]$ and why is it connected to $X^{-1}$. And moreover what is the difference between the probability measure and the random variable? That was the question, which you didn 't answer. Furthermore, saying WHAT something is, (yes also in mathematics!) is not equivalent to saying WHY something is what it is. Yours are definitions, which are absolutely meaningless to a beginner.

Comment: @Euler_Salter Thanks for your opinion. Did you read the answer at all? If you did, you might have noticed that, *contrarily to what you assert in your pair of (rather furious) comments*, the notation $X^{-1}$, when applied to a set, is explicitely defined in the answer.

Comment: @Did it depends on the definition of he Borel sigma algebra, which again is a new concept introduced by you. So for someone who doesn't know that, $X^{-1}$ is still rather too abstract and undefined.

Comment: @Euler_Salter The notation $X^{-1}$, as in $X^{-1}(C)$, "depends on the definition of he Borel sigma algebra", you say? Sorry but what are you talking about?

Comment: @Did I have to agree with Euler_Salter that this is a terrible and frankly useless answer. I have been looking for a similar problem as perfectly stated in the question but your answer makes little to no sense. All the problems are well written in that pair of "furious" comments. This is a reason for the downvote.

Comment: @leosenko Well,your comment offers quite a handful of definitive statements but when I am looking for their **reasons**, somehow I find myself failing to find any. So, until you add some plausible explanations for the wild allegations in your rant, please excuse me if I do not find them totally convincing. (But beware that when your compadre Salter tried to add some explanations for their own, similar, rant, they failed miserably. Again, maybe you will be more convincing than them and we shall be able to start a sensible discussion.)

Comment: @Did I specifically mentioned that the problems with your answer were well summarized by the other user. You were trying to defend your answer and I had to add to the discussion because I can evaluate your answer from the non-expert point of view and from that point of view, it is useless as you are assuming too much advanced knowledge as well as knowledge of the exact notation that you are using, e.g. $[X=a]=X−1({a})$ makes no sense unless the parenthesis have some special meaning like Poisson brackets have.

Comment: @Did,  (without their knowledge things like $\{A,B\}$ can have too many meanings, is it a two item set, is it an interval between numbers $A$ and $B$, what are those numbers anyway? etc). you talk about $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ but you do not define that thing and again assume that a beginner (which is evident from the question) has to have such knowledge which is a poor assumption.You can disagree all you want and downvote my other post all you like, that does not make your answer any better.At least suggest some literature.Please look at other posts to realise what a good answer looks like.

Comment: @Did all that said does not mean that your answer is wrong, just without good use.

Comment: @leosenko Again some big words thrown with no justification... but also some bits of what we should believe are examples of problems in this answer. Excellent! So, let us see the objections: you seem to mainly object to the identity $[X=a]=X^{-1}(\{a\})$ (not $X-1(a)$, please at least copy faithfully what you intend to criticize), as if the reader was required to know what $[X=a]$ means. Sorry but this is ludicrous since the LHS $[X=a]$ is **defined** as the RHS $X^{-1}(\{a\})$. So we are left with the claim that it is inacceptable to use the notation $X^{-1}(\{a\})$, ...

Comment: ... even though this notation is explained right away in my post by the second identity $X^{-1}(\{a\})=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=a\}$. Is it because the notation $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=a\}$ would be too esoteric and advanced to be understood by the OP? Hmmm... Likewise, you invent an idiotic meaning to $\{A,B\}$ (a notation not even used in my answer) as the interval from $A$ to $B$ instead of the pair with elements $A$ and $B$, although the former is unheard of (that is, from me, but surely you have tons of respectable references to provide in support of the interpretation ...

Comment: ... of $\{A,B\}$ as an interval?) and the latter is (according to me) nearly universal. At this point, I have two questions: 1) Are you serious? 2) How do you explain that the OP and other readers apparently got something from this answer? (FYI, the sentence "Please look at other posts to realise what a good answer looks like" in your comment seems to suggest that in fact you are either out of your depth or not serious or both.)

Comment: @Did you use the symbol $=$ for both definition and equality symbol, these are not the same as the former you assume, hope or simply say that is so, in the latter case you are necessarily using some theorem, axiom, or some way of reasoning that in the end you need to be able to prove. Thus if you write $[X=a]=X^{−1}(\{a\})=\{\omega\in\Omega∣X(ω)=a\}$, in my standard math world this is equivalence, not definition, thus the reader is supposed to be able to prove such equivalence. (and I appologize for missing the curly braces in my comment).

Comment: @Did In simple terms, in your answer, it is not clear what is definition, ie your notation and what is your claim. My point about parenthesis is very valid, every book can have its own notation for an interval as long as they define it. And yes, I am dead serious. If you looked at other peoples' answers, you would see how some people can go to depth in explanations. Yours is merely a sloppily written comment. No personal offence intended. Next, you claim you explain the notation $X^{−1}(\{a\})$, wrong again, the only thing you present is a series of equivalences without any explanation.

Comment: @leosenko Maybe you do not realize it but you are taking this answer to task, simply for using the language of set theory -- which many would consider as a prerequisite for even asking the question at hand. "Yours is merely a sloppily written comment" If this is your take on this answer (take that was negated by the OP themselves, it seems, more than three years ago, but you probably do not care), I think it is best to stop here.

Comment: @Did For what it's worth, I just stumbled across this answer and found it to be very useful for myself. Thank you.

Comment: @Did If there are multiple outcomes that get mapped to the same value $\alpha$, does this mean that for certain outcomes we can't get their probability? What I mean: suppose $\Omega = \{red, green, blue \}$. Both red and green are mapped to 1 while blue is mapped to 0. How we would calculate the $P(red)$? If we take $P(X=1)$ then it gives the probability $P( \{red, green \})$.