# probability measures vs. probability distributions vs. measure of probability density

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am learning probability theory right now and am confused about some basic concepts. I have a few questions and am wondering if you can also check if the following is correct:

Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}^1)$. My understanding is that:

1. $\mathbb{P}^1$ is called a *probability measure* but not a *probability distribution*.
2. If we have some random variable $X$ that maps to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, then $X$ induces a *probability distribution* $\mathbb{P}^2$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$, which is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ such that $\mathbb{P}^2(A) = \mathbb{P}^1(X^{-1}(A)), A \in \mathcal{B}$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is also a *probability measure* on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$?
3. We can consider a *probability density function* $f$ of $X$ with respect to some dominating measure $\mathbb{M}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Then $\mathbb{F}(A)=\int_A f ~d\mathbb{M}, A \in \mathcal{F}$ is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. Is it always true that $\mathbb{F}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$?
4. Must the random variable $X$ be defined on a probability space? From the above point, people often take the dominating measure $\mathbb{M}$ to be the Lebesgue measure. But the Lebesgue measure is not a probability measure...

Comment: after some searching, the answer for 2) is yes. In fact, it is a unique probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377642/what-is-the-difference-between-a-probability-distribution-on-events-and-random-v), for 3) the answer is yes according to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition). For 4) the answer is yes.

Comment: Probability distribution is more or less a synonym for a probability measure but a *distribution function* is something specially tied to probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. As for the concept of measures with density, it is much more general than the world of probability theory. If you are observing the measure with density $f$ w.r.t. $\mathbb{M}$, then the resulting measure is simply a probability measure if $f\geq 0$ and $\int f\textrm{d}\mathbb{M}=1$. Hence, the resulting measure need not be a probability measure, but *can* be a probability measure even if $\mathbb{M}$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not too late :)

1. A probability distribution is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, or more generally on a metric space, which is induced by a random variable or random element. By induced, I mean given a random variable $X : \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, the probability distribution of $X$ is the set function $$P_X : \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,1], P_X(A)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$$

Every probability measure on the real line (or a metric space) can be shown to be the probability distribution of some random variable (or random element). However, it is a convention that we only call a probability measure a probability distribution if it is the probability measure induced by a specified random variable (or element). It is only a convention though.

2. That is true. You can show that the three axioms of probability are satisfied. It comes from the fact that the inverse image works very nicely with set operations.
3. Yes. I'm assuming you mean that we have a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ as well as some dominating measure $\mathbb{M}$ on there. If $f$ is the density of $X$ then by definition of the density, $\forall A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,
   $$P_X(A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\int_A f(x)\, d\mathbb{M}(x)$$
   That is, $\mathbb{F}=P_X$ and so if you believe that $P_X$ is a probability measure, then so is $\mathbb{F}$.
4. Sort of no, not really. Things get a little confusing here. Given a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, any function $f : \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ which is measurable is called a measurable function. In the case that we have a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$, $f$ is still called a measurable function. In the special case that $\mu$ is a probability measure and we are working in probability theory then $X$ is conventionally used instead of $f$ and we call $X$ a random variable. So to answer your question, a random variable can be defined on any measurable space, not just probability space. But usually when you use the term 'random variable', it is implied that we are working with a probability space, in probability theory. In addition, be careful that the probability space on which a random variable is defined usually does not have the Lebesgue measure on there (unless you're working with say $[0, 1]$).